# Angular 6 - Pass data between two components via service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs

I'm trying to pass data between course-detail component and course-play component.
I used shared service and BehaviorSubject but it failed and I don't get any errors and it's not change anything. The only error I get when I open course-detail.html is "ERROR ReferenceError: course is not defined".
The data is passing correctly to course-detail through the service, it's just that I can't get the data back to the service so course-play can use it too. Here are the files:

**course.ts**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  course_id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  segment_id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
}
```

**course.service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ICourse } from './course';

// Inject Data from Rails app to Angular app
@Injectable()
export class CourseService{

  // JSON url to get data from
  private url = 'http://localhost:3000/courses';
  private courseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/courses.json';

  // Subscribe data
  private courseData = new BehaviorSubject<ICourse>(null);
  public courseData$ = this.courseData.asObservable();

  // here we set/change value of the observable
  setData(course) {
    this.courseData.next(course)
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Handle Any Kind of Errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    // A client-side or network error occured. Handle it accordingly.
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occured:', error.error.message);
    }

    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    else {
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code ${error.status}, ' +
        'body was ${error.error}');
    }

    // return an Observable with a user-facing error error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happend; please try again later.');
  }

  // Get All Courses from Rails API App
  getCourses(): Observable<ICourse[]> {
  const coursesUrl = `${this.url}` + '.json';

  return this.http.get<ICourse[]>(coursesUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // Get Single Course by id. will 404 if id not found
  getCourse(id: number): Observable<ICourse> {
    const detailUrl = `${this.url}/${id}` + '.json';

    return this.http.get<ICourse>(detailUrl)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }


}
```

**course-detail.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Course-detail decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.sass']
})

export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  course: ICourse;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
  }

  // On start of the life cycle
  ngOnInit() {
    // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getCourse(id);
    }

   // Get course detail by id
   getCourse(id: number) {
     this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
       course => this.course = course,
       error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
       this.courseService.setData(course))
   }

   // When we click the back button in browser
   onBack(): void {
     this.router.navigate(['/courses']);
   }

}
```

**course-play.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Couse-play decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-play-course-play',
  templateUrl: './course-play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-play.component.sass']
})

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  courseData: ICourse;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) {
        courseService.courseData$.subscribe( courseData => this.courseData = courseData)
  }

    // On start of the life cycle
    ngOnInit() {
        // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      }

    // When we click the back button in browser
     onBack(): void {
       this.router.navigate(['/courses/:id']);
     }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or a plunker please?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this.courseService.setData(course)` function in wrong place.

replace the below code in **course-detail.component**

```
  // Get course detail by id
   getCourse(id: number) {
     this.courseService.getCourse(id).subscribe(
       course =>  {
          this.course = course;
          this.courseService.setData(course);
       },
       error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      )
   }
```

Comment: thank you! now it's not display any errors but when I try to access the data in the hrml file of course-play, nothing is showing (the *ngIf worked, but when I wrote: <h3>{{courseData.title}}</h3> nothing was showing and no error in the console

Comment: when I enter course-play through course-detail it's working, but when I refresh the page nothing showing